# Client-to-Client VoIP Voice SDK Call with Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

I am trying to make a VoIP client-to-client call using Twilio's Voice SDK. So far I am able to have my iPhone dial my Android phone and vice-versa but can only hear an automated voice say the "to" client's identity instead of both phones being able to just talk to each other. Am I missing something here?

For both platforms, I am just using the sample repos Twilio provided. For the server, I am using Twilio's sample NodeJS server-less code.

```
// /place-call

...

var url = 'https://' + context.DOMAIN_NAME + '/incoming';
const client = context.getTwilioClient();

client.calls.create({
    url: url,
    to: 'client:' + to,
    from: event.From,
}, function(err, result) {    
    // End our function
    if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
    } else {
        callback(null, "<Response/>");
    }
});

...

// /incoming

...

const toClient = (event.To).replace('client:', '');
const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

const dial = twiml.dial();
const client = dial.client();
client.identity(toClient);
callback(null, twiml.toString());

...
```

When I look at the logs, I see the "/incoming" endpoint returning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Client>
            <Identity>android_user</Identity>
        </Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The issue is that you are returning the TwiML as a string and Twilio Functions then deem the response to be of Content-Type `text/plain`. Twilio then reads the content as if it was a `<Say>`.

It is an easy fix though. Change:

```js
callback(null, twiml.toString());
```

to

```js
callback(null, twiml);
```

Twilio Functions will recognise that the `twiml` variable is of type `VoiceResponse` and set the Content-Type to `text/xml` and your application will work as expected.